# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.type') react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new with react native and I'm building an app with sign in and sign up interfaces, trying to use (this.props.type) to control signings/signup button, but I got an error in my code, hope you guys help me :)

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

const Form: () => React$Node = () => {

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                   underlineColorAndroid= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                   placeholder= "Phone Number"
                   autoCorrect={true}
                   textContentType="telephoneNumber"
                   keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation"
                   placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
        />

        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                   underlineColorAndroid= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                   placeholder= "Email"
                   autoCorrect={true}
                   textContentType="emailAddress"
                   keyboardType="email-address"
                   placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
        />

        <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                   underlineColorAndroid= 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                   placeholder= "Email Password"
                   secureTextEntry={true}
                   placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
        />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
};
```

I also use these to lines in both sign in and sign up files :

```
<Form types="SignUp"/>
<Form types="SignIn"/>
```

Comment: `{props.types}` should have to be there. and `props` should have to be pass as an argument to the functional component. `const Form: () => React$Node = (props) => {`

Comment: thank you for your response but it also did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `Form` to receive params

```
const Form: ({ types }) => React$Node = () => {
```

then use it like

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{types} </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and render your form

```
<Form types="SignUp"/>
<Form types="SignIn"/>
```

Form component without typescript

```
const Form = ({ types }) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputBox}
      underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      placeholder="Phone Number"
      autoCorrect={true}
      textContentType="telephoneNumber"
      keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation"
      placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
    />

    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputBox}
      underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      placeholder="Email"
      autoCorrect={true}
      textContentType="emailAddress"
      keyboardType="email-address"
      placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
    />

    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputBox}
      underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      placeholder="Email Password"
      secureTextEntry={true}
      placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
    />

    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{types} </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it gives me an error ( TransFormError SyntaxError ) for const Form: ({ types }) => React$Node = () => {

Comment: remove ```React$Node``` and use it like ```const Form = ({ types }) => (```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Text you are fetching `this.props.type` `<Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type} </Text>` but you are passing types `<Form types="SignUp"/>`

So change inside Text to

```
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.types} </Text>
```

hope it helps

Comment: it won't work because ```Form``` is not a class component

Comment: I'm watching this tutorial and it is work with him https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K41vd_W2qE at the 49m

Comment: also Form is one of my projects file so ? what should I use

Comment: @Ar. are you using typescript?

Comment: @Ar. please see my answer below with the component that doesn't use typescript.